# Call function from DLL

Tags: c#, vb.net, function, dll, reference

It is well known that you can have functions in a dll, reference the DLL and then call the functions from your main executable.
I like to know if the reverse way is also possible?
So I like to call a function in the main executable from the dll, without having the actual function that should be called inside the dll.
Reason: I am working on a pluginsystem.

Answer (score 1):

You're sort of comparing apples and oranges: referencing a dll by the build system is completely different from a plugin system where everything happens at runtime. Typically a plugin system where you would want to call some functions from the plugin host (your exe) would be like this (simplified):

```
//in a common project
//functions from the host that will be callable by the plugin
public interface PluginHost
{
  void Foo();
}

//the plugin
public interface Plugin
{
  void DoSomething( PluginHost host );
}

//in the exe
class ThePluginHost : PluginHost
{
  //implement Foo
}

//in the plugin
class ThePlugin : Plugin
{
  //implement DoSomething,
  //has access to exe methods through PluginHost
}

//now al that's left is loading the plugin dll dynamically,
//and creating a Plugin object from it.
//Can be done using Prism/MEF etc, that's too broad of a scope for this answer
PluginHost host = new ThePluginHost();
Plugin plugin = CreatePluginInstance( "/path/to/dll" );
plugin.DoSomething( host );
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, executables can be added as reference in your project and you can use them same way you call functions from referenced dlls